# Conditional statement syntax help

Tags: c#, wpf

I am going through this WPF tutorial http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/alanl/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=18 and I have a question about the CountToFontSizeConverter section of the tutorial. Could someone please explain the return statement to me i.e

```
return ((minFontSize + count + increment) < maxFontSize) ? 
         (minFontSize + count + increment) : maxFontSize;
```

I understand it's a conditional but the syntax looks rather bespoke. If possible could someone re-write this in a simpler way? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "somewhat bespoke" but it's worth breaking down.

Original:

```
return ((minFontSize + count + increment) < maxFontSize) 
      ? (minFontSize + count + increment) : maxFontSize;
```

Broken down:

```
bool condition = (minFontSize + count + increment) < maxFontSize;
if (condition)
{
    return minFontSize + count + increment;
}
else
{
    return maxFontSize;
}
```

Better approach - far more readable:

```
return Math.Min(minFontSize + count + increment, maxFontSize);
```

In general, you can usually replace an expression of the form

```
a < b ? a : b
```

with

```
Math.Min(a, b)
```

assuming that `a` and `b` are of numeric types. It's not always the case, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: Bespoke, according to Wikipedia is supposedly a British English word for "Tailor made down to the fabric and exact cuts" although given that you live there...

Comment: @Cpfohl: Yes, I'm happy with "bespoke" as a word in general - but I don't see where it fits in here :)

Comment: Perhaps 'bespoke' was the wrong word. Maybe I should have said 'unusual' as I am still learning C# and this syntax is unfamiliar to me :)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
return ((minFontSize + count + increment) < maxFontSize) ? (minFontSize + count + increment) : maxFontSize;
```

Effectively translates to:

```
if ((minFontSize + count + increment) < maxFontSize)
     return (minFontSize + count + increment);
else
     return maxFontSize;
```

In this case, since the goal is to prevent the expression from being larger than "maxFontSize", I'd personally just use:

```
return Math.Min(minFontSize + count + increment, maxFontSize);
```

I find this expresses the intent much more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the [ternary conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) (or simply the conditional operator), and can be rewritten as:

```
if ((minFontSize + count + increment) < maxFontSize) 
{
  return minFontSize + count + increment;
}

return maxFontSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cache = (minFontSize + count + increment);

return (cache < maxFontSize) ? cache : maxFontSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing but a conditional operator from C#. Syntax is like following
**Condition ? Statement1 (if true) : Statement2 (if false)** 
If your condition returns true, Statement1 is run and if turns out be false, Statement2 is run.

In your case if (minFontSize + count + increment) > maxFontSize , maxFontSize is evaluated else  (minFontSize + count + increment)